This "installment loan provider" has stated that they need to make a deposit of anywhere from 200 to 400 which I am required to send back
They want me to send it back using a prepaid card, Cash App, or something of that nature. They are telling me the reason is my "low" credit rating and that it's for PPI Insurance, and once that is done, they will deposit my requested loan amount.
Obviously, red flags go up everywhere, but I want to be sure that it's a scam. What damage can happen to me if I do it?

100% scam. Stop all contact immediately.

If you could be sure it was a scam, then you would be sure it was a scam and stay away. It's almost certainly a scam but there's no way to be certain without going through it.  The damage is you lose your 200-400 deposit.

The money they send you will be reversible and/or from a hacked account. The money you send them will not be reversible. There will be no loan, and you will lose everything you sent them.

@DStanley We can be sure. There is no “almost”. This is definitely illegitimate. Sure there’s some uncertainty as to the details (i.e. whether it’s an advance-fee scam or money laundering) but there is no doubt: this is not a legitimate lender.

And if it's a typical scam, the $400 fee is just the tip of the iceberg. They will find an excuse to ask for another payment, trying to leverage the sunk cost fallacy as you try to recover that first payment. This will go on as long as they can keep you on the hook. The only way to win is to stop now, walk away, and report it to the appropriate governmental agency for appropriate action. Which may be limited to tracking statistics and trying to warn other potential victims, but it's better than nothing.

Thank you so much for your input. I want you to knoe I followed your advice and although I haven't gotten the money I needed yet, I am grateful to know that I didn't go down the rabbit hole. One less person being scammed!!

Scam! Do not proceed.
It's an advance fee scam or perhaps this. Either way, this it's not legitimate.
However much money you send would be gone. If you give them personal information (e.g., SSN), they could sell it or use it for identity theft. A legitimate loan company won't take "fees" via gift cards or Cash App.
Or, if they give you money and you return it, they might reverse the transaction where they gave you money after you've paid them (via some hard-to-reverse method), meaning you're out however much you send as they undo giving you money. One example would be if they transfer you funds from a stolen account.

I think that it's more likely that it's either a paper-hanging scam or a money mule scam.

Note that, when connection to an account does have to be tested, the test will generally be $1 or less, and in many cases will actually be two or four transfers, making deposits and then canceling them, and asking you to tell them what the amounts were to confirm that they have the right account information.
If it's a larger amount, and they want you to send it back, assume a scam or money laundering.

This is a classic scam. This will work one of two ways:

They'll deposit money in a reversible form and manipulate you into sending them the money in an irreversible form. Their deposit will be reversed, but you won't be able to get the money back. For example, if they paid you by check, the check will eventually bounce (but you'll already have paid them the money in a way that can't be reversed).
The money they send you will have been stolen or otherwise fraudulently acquired. This is known as a money-mule scam.

